# How does jQuery construct an Ajax POST request with JSON string data

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to hit a web site endpoint from a Java servlet using HttpClient (v4.1). The endpoint expects a post request containing parameters in a JSON string, from what I can tell. I say "from what I can tell" because I have some sample jquery production code that makes successful requests to the endpoint. It looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some/u/r/l",
    data: "{'keyA':'valueA','keyB':'valueB','keyC':'valueC'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    ...
```

So I'm trying to replicate this behavior from a Java servlet using HttpClient, but I'm getting ambiguous 500's from the server, so I must be creating the request incorrectly. Can anyone tell me exactly what jQuery is doing in the above code. I understand that using a JS object as value for `data` parameter will add the respective key-value pairs as URL parameters to the request, but what happens to the JSON string as in the above example? Where does it go?

Comment: All browsers these days have developer tools that allow you to inspect the HTTP traffic. Try hitting F12 and looking at the 'network' tab in your browser whilst performing the jQuery post. You should see the raw HTTP POST request.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON string needs to be added to the request body. For HttpClient (4.1) this goes something like:

```
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "application/json", HTTP.UTF_8));
```